# Can't get node.js openshift app running, ERROR: listen EACCESS

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have browsed several other questions related to this and I have yet to find a solution. When I log onto open shift via their website and try to open my app I get a 503 Service Unavailable error. When I ssh into my app and try to run server.js i get the error:

`events.js:72
 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
       ^
Error: listen EACCES
at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1024:19)` and it just keeps on going like this for several lines.

My server.js looks like this:

```
var express       = require('express'),
app               = express(),
bodyParser        = require('body-parser'),
mongoose          = require('mongoose'),
meetupsController = require('./server/controllers/meetups-controller');

var http = require('http');
app.set('port', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080); //testing
app.set('ip', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'); //testing

//mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mean-demo'); //for local use

mongoose.connect('mongodb://user_name:password@host:port/mean-demo')
//note: mean-demo is name of the database not my appname.
//I have replaced mean-demo with my appname (testapp) and it still doesn't work

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/views/index.html');
});

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/client/js'));

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), app.get('ip'), function(){ //testing
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

//REST API
app.get('/api/meetups', meetupsController.list);
app.post('/api/meetups', meetupsController.create);

app.listen(8080, function(){ //was 3000
    console.log('I\'m Listening...');
}) //i have commented these out and the problem still isn't fixed
```

I have tried implementing various changes to this code, moving things around, etc..., and nothing works. I have also commented out the mongoose/mongodb calls and I still get the error. This does work locally with a local version of mongo DB by the way. I really have no idea how to fix this, so some guidance would be much appreciated. Like I said before, I have searched around stackoverflow, and a lot of people have this error, but nothing that seemed to fix theirs has fixed mine. Let me know if you need any other pieces of information and I will be glad to supply them.

EDIT:
So it is working now. I think what was happening is this: I know the EADDRINUSE error is when you are accessing a port that is already in use. I think what was happening was that my app was up and running, so when I tried to run it, it was trying to run it twice, and was throwing the error. I had been grinding away on the openshift CLI for so long I didn't bother to check my app on a web browser to see if it was working. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try referring to this sample code (https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-nodejs-http-and-websocket-example/blob/master/server.js)

I think what you are missing is that

```
app.listen(8080, function(){ //was 3000
    console.log('I\'m Listening...');
})
```

should be

```
app.listen( port, ipaddress, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8080');
});
```

Basically you are listening on the correct port, but you are trying to probably bind to all interfaces (0.0.0.0) instead of your node.js port.

Comment: As you can see from my first call to listen, I do call it with the port and ip address

Answer (score 0):

you're calling `listen` twice.  The first one probably succeeds, but the second one fails with `EACCES` because something is already listening on the port.

Comment: I commented it out a while ago and I thought nothing happened. But on second look, my error goes from EACCES to EADDRINUSE. I will go about searching how to solve this (unless you know how off the top of your head). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction